# Pdf Reader documents are not upload correctly to windows azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I try to upload a pdf document to azure storage, it's uploaded to blob storage with a specific URL. The problem is when I try to open the pdf document in a browser using that URL, it does not open.

I checked the source pdf document and the uploaded blob sizes are 2.8 Mb and 0 Kb respectively. After saving that blob to my system, when I try to open it using Adobe Reader it will display the error:

> 'Adobe Reader could not open the doc.pdf it is either not supported
>   file type or because of the file damaged'.

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("GetPdf", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = multipart/form-data" })){ %>

    <input type="file" id="Document" name="Document" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br /><%} %>
```

Controller:

```
// When I upload the pdf document by default am getting below:
// properties[ContentLength(size of document), ContentType(application/pdf),
// FileName(name of the document), InputStream(System.web.HttpInputStream)]

Public Action Result GetPdf(HttpPostedFileBase Document)
{
    var inputstream = Document.InputStream;
    var filename = Document.FileName;
    var doctype=Document.ContentType;              

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting

("StorageConnectionString"));
      CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documentscontainer");               
                container.CreateIfNotExists();              
                var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
                permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
                container.SetPermissions(permissions);              
                string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("rewhizzdocuments/{0}",filename);
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
                blob.Properties.ContentType = doctype;    
                blob.UploadFromStream(inputstream);
}
```

When I applied the same code (the code I used for the pdf document) to uploading images, they are uploaded into blob storage and I can get the images using the blob URL.

Any ideas on how to sort this problem out would be appreciated.